# Adding a list of contacts in Outlook is very very slow - C# Outlook Add-in

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in, outlook-addin

I have a problem while writing Outlook ContactItem in Outlook using an Outlook Add-in that I developed  in C#.
I get a list of contacts from a webservice and I want to put them in Outlook.
I did this:

```
List<MyContactObject> lst = getListFromWebService();
Outlook.ContactItem ci = null;

foreach(MyContactObject cto in lst)
{
    ci = this.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olContactItem) as Outlook.ContactItem;
    ci = FillOutlookContact(ci, cto);
    ci.Save();
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ci);
}
```

and here is the `FillOutlookContact` method:

```
private Outlook.ContactItem FillOutlookContact(Outlook.ContactItem ci, MyContactObject cto)
{
    ci.CompanyName = cto.ClientName;
    ci.FullName = cto.ContactName;
    ci.BusinessTelephoneNumber = cto.Telephone;
    ci.BusinessFaxNumber = cto.Fax;
    ci.MobileTelephoneNumber = cto.Mobile;
    ci.Email1Address = cto.Email;
    return ci;
}
```

All this code runs and works, but it is very very slow. The list lst contains 26.000 contacts...
is there a better way to do this stuff? Currently it takes about 30 mn to write all the list in Outlook.
I use a `BackgroundWorker` to run this code.

The `getListFromWebService()` is not the problem, I get the list in less than 1 second (I know it because I put a `MessageBox.Show("here!");` just after the method and it ran in 1 second)

Can you help me to find a solution to my problem?.

EDIT : I tried to remove the `FillOutlookContact` method and put it directly in the other method and it doesn't seem to work better.

Comment: You sure that pulling from the webservice isn't the slow part and not Outlook?

Comment: Well the problem seems to be that you're looping through 26000 contacts and then creating each one, one at a time in the foreach statement. Is there no way to do it in bulk?

Comment: If you are managing to create 26,000 contacts in 30 minutes, then you're doing fantastic. In my experience developing many such solutions, you can only expect to create 1-2 contacts per second!